# PEM with multiple independent certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl

NGINX supports client-side certificate authentication through the `ssl_client_certificate` directive. NGINX only allows this directive to be used once with a single PEM file.

I want to allow certificates signed from multiple independent Certificate Authorities, thus multiple PEM files.

Is it allowed to concatenate multiple PEM files into a single PEM file and use this for the `ssl_client_certificate` directive in NGINX?

As I understand it a PEM file contains a certificate chain. If I were to concatenate multiple PEM files (thus certificate chains) then there would be no indication of where a certificate chain starts or ends. Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Yes, you can put multiple certificates in this file - https://serverfault.com/a/653879

Answer (score 0):

TLS allows only a single leaf certificate with its chain to be used for certificate based authentication. It is thus not possible to have multiple independent client certificates at the same time.